# How to upload instant playable video to telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon, pyrogram

I am making a telegram bot to upload videos in my local PC. But when I sent the video, that message is very dumb. like this

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxd7x.png)

**But I need videos like this**

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpwal.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tayS.png)

my code is

```
from pyrogram import Client
app = Client(
    "session",
    api_id=329,
    api_hash="7943a36fdcf9"
    )
with app:
    app.send_video(chat_id = channel, video = 'vid.mp4',supports_streaming = True)
```

is there any specific specific methods for sending a proper video? How can I send a video properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video file is too big. Telegram will handle videos `< 10 MB` and automatically create a thumbnail for you. For videos larger than that you'll have to supply the information about the video yourself. Resolution (width and height), length, thumbnail, etc..

Additionally, you can omit the `supports_streaming` argument, as Pyrogram defaults this to `True` anyway.

To get information about your video you could use something like ffprobe.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_video?highlight=send_video#pyrogram.Client.send_video) show that you can add arguments `caption` and `thumb` to your call to `send_video`.